# How to add a redirection button to jqGrid with a rowID parameter

Tags: button, jqgrid, parameter-passing, formatter, rowid

I'm using jqGrid to display a database table on screen, and I need to add at the end of every row a button that redirects me to another page (let's call it page2.php) AND that passes the value of the row ID through to that page.

I've added a column in colModel with a formatter but I can't seem to find the right function to add a functionnal button (the redirection works fine but I have trouble with the ID passing) :

```
{name:'refresh', index:'refresh', width:70, align:'center', formatter:refreshButton}
```

And the corresponding function :

```
function refreshButton(cellvalue, options, rowobject){
    return '<button type="button" onclick="window.location=\'page2.php\'">Go</button>';
}
```

i found somewhere that adding `?id="+rowid+"&oper=edit` after `page2.php` would work to pass the rowID but then the redirection won't work anymore...

I'd gladly use some help with that, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me any time I click on the button

```
function refreshButton(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
    return '<button type="button" onclick="location.href=\'page2.php?oper=edit&id='+options.rowId+'\'">Go</button>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was going crazy with these simple/double quotes, your code works perfectly.